# Abrir formulario creado, Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms, formularios

Tengo el form inicial llamado "start", y un botón llamado "run".
Ahora tengo creado un form adicional que se llama "runf".
Cómo puedo abrir "runf" desde el botón "run".
He intentado mirar en la internet, y la respuesta es la siguiente..

```
Form Formulario = New Form();
Formulario.Show();
Hide();
```

Pero no quiero crear un formulario desde código, quiero abrir un formulario que ya tengo creado.
En VB.NET se hacía solo con Formulario.Show(); Alguien puede explicarme porque en C# es totalmente diferente? O estoy equivocado, bueno, no tengo idea.

Answer (score 3):

Para poder llamar o aun formulario debes instanciarlo
VB.Net

```
Dim frm As New Form2()
frm.Show()
```

C#

```
frmBusqueda frm = new frmBusqueda
frm.Show
```

Comment: Pero es que no entiendo, en VB simplemente daba click en crear nuevo Form y llamaba ese Form solo con Show. Estoy enredado

Comment: es que vb te escondia mucha del codigo por eso se realizaba directo, en c# trabjas con clases y objetos por eso debes crear la instancia del form usando el "new" y sobre esa instancia invocas el metodo Show()

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esto podria ayudar

[Cómo: Mostrar un formulario desde otro (Visual C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/ws1btzy8(v=vs.90).aspx)

veras que alli define

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    frm.Show();
}
// Create Form2.
public class Form2: Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        Text = "Form2";
    }
}
```

usa el `new` para crear la instancia del form (recuerda el form es una clase que debe instanciarse) y luego sobre la instancia usas el Show() para mostrar el forma visualmente.

Recuerda que en c# todos son objetos incluidos el form

Comment: Estoy realmente confundido con todo esto. Por qué Form2 no puede ser independiente de Form1?

Comment: a que llamas independiente? cada form es una clase diferente que sera usadas para crear instancias de objetos, en ese punto son independientes. Quizas el problema es que deberias leer algo relacionado a la POO (Programacion orientada a obietos), por ejemplo concoes que es una clase ? sino lo sabes alli esta el problema del prorque te parece confuso

Comment: Había venido trabajando con VB.NET, y la cuestión era diferente, cuando le dabas click en Crear nuevo Windows Form, tan sólo era cuestión de llamarlo con Show(); desde el Form principal. Sin necesidad de que en el código del Form principal (Form1) se cree el Form2. Eso es lo que me tiene confundido

Comment: ok pero vb.net no es igual a c#, sigo pensando que deberias leer algo mas sobre POO para entrar en tema. Ademas esto que comentas de vb.net es porque el lenguaje te enmascara la creacion de la instancia, pero como comenta Pedro tambien tiene el "New" en vb.net para crear la instancia del form (lo cual seria la forma correcta)

Comment: Cuando creas un form desde "Crear nuevo Windows Forms" se asigna un codigo para dicho Form que obviamente es independiente de Form1, ahora bien `Form2 frm = new Form2();` a lo que entendí es que el Form2 se está creando desde Form1, entonces habría necesidad de ir a Proyecto - Agregar Windows Forms? Pensé que esto sería más sencillo.

Comment: la instancia del form2 lo realizas desde codigo, pero debes tener el archivo que define el formulario, porque basicamente con la opcion de "Agregar Windows Forms" del menu creas el diseñador donde programar la logica del form2, por eso te comentaba una cosa es la definicion de la clase y otra es la instancia

Comment: Voy a editar más tarde la pregunta para que veas bien lo que intento decir.

Answer (score 1):

Te presento una solucion que implemente en un formulario principal con links a ventanas contenidas.

```
//Variable global a la clase
 Private ventana As FrmVentana = Nothing


//On click sobre el link en la ventana principal al que despliega el el FrmVentana contenida
If (ventana Is Nothing OrElse Not ventana.CanFocus) Then
    ventana = New FrmVentana
    ventana.MdiParent = Me
    ventana.setearUser(Me.usuario)
    ventana.Show()
    ventana.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
Else
    ventana.Focus()
End If
```

Espero que te sirva, estol hace que cuando presionas el link si aun no fue creada o por algo no puede mostrarla, la crea. En caso contrario muestra la ya existente.

Saludos

Comment: Lamento haberlo puesto en vb.net, pero es trasaladable a c# <br/>    if (ventana == null || !ventana.CanFocus){
    ventana = new FrmVentana();    
    ventana.Show();
    ventana.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    }
    else{
    ventana.Focus();
    }

Comment: Estaria bueno que nos comentes que tal te fue y que respuesta te fue util. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero este código. Usa el form que aparece por defecto sin cambiarle el nombre (quedando como Form1) y crea un boton, cambiale el nombre por run1, le haces dobleclick y le pegas el contenido que corresponde en este texto; Acomoda lo demás como aparece en el ejemplo.

> public partial class Form1 : Form
>
> {
>
> ```
> public Form1()
>   {
>   InitializeComponent();
>   }
>
> private Form runf;
>
> private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>   {
>   runf = new Form()
>     {
>     Size = new Size (200,100),
>     Location = new Point (200,250),
>     ShowInTaskbar = false,
>     WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized,
>     };
>
>   runf.Show();
>   // Resto del codigo del inicio de "start" (Form1) ...
>   }
>
> private void run1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
>   {
>   if (runf.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
>     runf.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
>   else
>     runf.Focus();
>   }
>
> // Resto de metodos del programa ...
> ```
>
> }
>
> Te sugiero que no uses nombres como Start o Run, porque pueden coincidir 
>      con palabras especiales, o utilizadas para / por C# y dar conflictos a
>      la hora de interpretarlos.

Answer (score 1):

Si entendí bien, estas trabajando en Visual C#, tu Form inicial es "start", y el botón llamado "run" es el que va a llevarte al formulario "runf", tengo las lineas de codigo que necesitas y son exactamente las siguientes:

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2 ();
        f.Visible = true;
        this.Dispose(false);
    }
```

Para que esta instrucción te sirva tienes que tomar las siguientes consideraciones:

"Form1" deberá ser para tu caso "Start"; 
"f" podrá ser cualquier variable con la cual quieras identificar la instrucción; 
"Form2" deberá ser para tu caso "Runf"; 
"Button" deberá ser "Run".

Cabe destacar que si no quieres que se cierre el formulario "Start" cuando abra el formulario "Runf", deberás quitar la linea de código

```
    this.Dispose(false);
```

y listo una vez que tomes estas consideraciones lo pruebas, espero te sirva.